# python import from relative paths

Tags: python-2.7, import, io, path

Question about setting up a relative path import. I have a bunch of files (modules) that live in
'/Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/common/
such as:

1. /Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/common/constants.py
2. /Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/common/util/misc.py

Each of those modules has a line to import other modules from within the common/ directory as needed. Examples:

"constants.py" in (/Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/common/constants.py) contains the line:

- import programX.common.util.misc as util_misc

And "misc.py" in (/Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/common/util/misc.py) contains the line:

- import programX.common.constants as constants

Now I want to use those modules. How do I properly let python know to set the correct path dependencies so that it will know to  look into (/Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/common/) and the subdirectories inside common?

I tried appending the path, but it does not work:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/')
>>> import programX.common.constants.py as constants
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named programX.common.constants.py
>>> 
>>> sys.path.append('/Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/common/')
>>> sys.path.append('/Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/programX/common/util')
>>> 
>>> import programX.common.constants.py as constants
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named programX.common.constants.py
>>> 
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/myname'
>>> 
>>> import Desktop.programX_files.programX.common.constants.py as constants
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Desktop.programX_files.programX.common.constants.py
>>>
```

I'm guessing it might be some relatively simple solution, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
import sys
# set path to folder
sys.path.append('/Users/myname/Desktop/programX_files/')
# now import files
import programX.common.constants.py as constants
```